# Activating and deactivating a command button based on a cell value

Tags: vba, button

I'm relatively new but learning quickly.  I have a cell (Sheet8.Range("E15")) that produces TRUE or FALSE (boolean) based on other conditions.  My goal is that when this cell = TRUE, the button is active.  If cell value changes to FALSE, I want the button to be inactive.  Thanks for the help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Sheet8.Range("E15")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

      If Sheet8.Range("E15").Value = True Then CommandButton1.Enabled = True
      If Sheet8.Range("E15").Value = False Then CommandButton1.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here looks to be that the cell value isn't actually changing, which is not triggering the macro.

If you change the macro from a Worksheet_Change to a Selection_Change, this macro will be triggered after every user action.  This should solve your issue.

Use the KeyCells.Value instead of the sheet and change the Button name to something more description.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Sheet8.Range("E15")

If KeyCells.Value = TRUE Then 
     CommandButton1.Enabled = True
Else
     CommandButton1.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```